# how to debug a program that calls a WCF Service,

Tags: c#, wcf, service, message-queue, visual-studio-debugging

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I have a very simple asp.net webpage, I browse and upload an xml file, and I have 2 textboxes for now. In the left box, I show the original xml content, and then, I want to call the WCF service, using the xml as input, and display the result returned in the right box.

Right now, I keep getting an error of "Message Service Queue is not available". I have set the system account for message queue service from google searching.

So now, I need to debug the service. After searching around, I thought attach to process might be a good approach. However, in my collegue's machine, restarting the service is so fast that I cannot stop it and click Debug->Attach to Process->select_exe, and to be honest, it's weird that it doesn't stop at the OnStart function at all...

WCF is hosted as windows service.

Could anyone give me any ideas or hints from your experience and knowledge? Or any other approach that you think might be good in my situation.

Any ideas are appreciated. Great thanks. =)

Comment: If this is a service you control just put in a Debugger.Launch() at the beginning of it to attach to it

Comment: @Abhinav I put a break point at the OnStart function, I tried to restart the service so that the service stops then starts, it doesn't stop at the onstart function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the service code so that it detects either that it's running from the debugger using the [`Environment.UserInteractive` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or simply that it's in debug mode (`#ifdef DEBUG`) (rather than release) and then start the program as a console application rather than a service.

For example:

```
    static void Main()
    {
#ifdef DEBUG
        Application.Run();
#else
        ServiceBase service = new SampleService(); 
        ServiceBase.Run(service); 
#endif
    }
```

This will allow you to set break points and step into code in one instance of Visual Studio while you run the client code in another.

Comment: Thats the change I was talking about. This way you can get rid of SCM.

Comment: @ChrisF♦ Thank you. Also, a question relating testing aside: does stub, moq and moles relates to my problem, should i spend time exploring it for my current project?

Comment: @ChrisF♦ as I only browse and run 1 xml file at a time, does it mean i am doing unit testing and spend time exploring those stubs, moq and moles please?

Comment: @user2751691 please ask a new question about this.

Answer (score 0):

How is this WCF service hosted? Web Service, Windows Service, Console App, etc? in any case you can debug that app in VS and let your application hit it. For Windows Service you will have to change the code a bit for debugging.

Comment: It's hosted as windows service

Comment: Thank you. Also, a question relating testing aside: does stub, moq and moles relates to my problem, should i spend time exploring it for my current project?